# Регулярное выражение для валидации GUID

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Задание:Написать регулярное выражение, определяющее является ли данная строка GUID с или без скобок. Где GUID это строчка, состоящая из 8, 4, 4, 4, 12 шестнадцатеричных цифр разделенных тире.

– пример правильных выражений: e02fd0e4-00fd-090A-ca30-0d00a0038ba0. 
– пример неправильных выражений: e02fd0e400fd090Aca300d00a0038ba.

Решение:

```
public static boolean second(String testString)
{
  Pattern p  = Pattern.compile("^[{]?\\w{8}-\\w{4}-\\w{4}-\\w{12}[}]?$");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(testString);
  return m.matches();
}
```

Понимаю, что ошибка в шаблоне, но не понимаю почему?

Comment: скобки фигурные?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы пропустили одну группу из 4 символов. Вот исправленный вариант.

```
Pattern p =  Pattern.compile("^\\{?\\p{XDigit}{8}-\\p{XDigit}{4}-\\p{XDigit}{4}-\\p{XDigit}{4}-\\p{XDigit}{12}}?$");
```

Вот мой вариант

```
Pattern p =  Pattern.compile("^\\{?\\p{XDigit}{8}-(?:\\p{XDigit}{4}-){3}\\p{XDigit}{12}}?$");
```

Вы так же может отлаживать свои выражения на [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/). Там это очень удобно делать.

Comment: спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант:

```
Pattern p  = Pattern.compile(@"^[{(]?[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-([0-9a-fA-F]{4}-){3}[0-9a-fA-F]{12}[)}]?$");
```

Почему вместо конструкции `0-9a-fA-F` не использую `\w` ? 
Согласно [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) для спец. символа `\w` используется такое объявление `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`, а GUID исключает знак нижнего подчеркивания.

Comment: спасиибо за разъяснения

Comment: @bsuart2017, если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).